# watch cannot work with pinia and Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch, vue-composition-api, pinia

I have this code `store.js`

```
export default defineStore('global', () => {
    const packagesList = reactive([])
    
    function getSearch() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            packagesList.splice(0, packagesList.length, ...[1,2,3])
            
        }, 1000);
    }
  
    return { packagesList, getSearch}
  })
```

and code in component

```
<script setup>
import { watch } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import Store from '@/store/index'

const store = Store()
const { packagesList } = storeToRefs(store)

setTimeout(()=>{
  store.getSearch()
},1000)

watch(
  () => packagesList,
  {deep: true},
  (count, prevCount) => {
    console.log(count, prevCount)
  }
)

</script>
```

And - `watch` - not working. I don`t have answer - why)

...a few words so that it doesn't look like my post is basically code;

Comment: The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The code that you posted is supposed to work.

Comment: I see two "nested" setTimeout, but this is just a side note. The main issue is that you define `packagesList` as `reactive`. This returns an object and not the array you are expecting. I would assume there are some errors in the console. I would use `ref` instead. Also I don't now if the reactivity on arrays works with `splice`. Also you are not really using Pinia, as you don't implement the state: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/

Comment: @Thomas reactive works on several object types that are supported by Vue, including arrays. splice and other public array methods are supported. Pinia state is implemented with setup function, https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores

Comment: @EstusFlask - yes, code is supposed to work. But doesn`t. Try

Comment: @EstusFlask, Meanwhile, if I set `watch` on `Option API` - it is work

Comment: I see. watch options are messed up. `deep` should go the last. And it's better to add refs as is. So it should be `watch(packagesList, (count, prevCount) => {}, { deep: true })`, and also count === prevCount in this case.

Comment: @EstusFlask ok, I remember that `reactive([])` didn't work as expected when I tried it a while back, maybe that was fixed since then. I mostly use `ref` in my code...

Comment: @EstusFlask  `watch options are messed up.`  - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `ref` instead of `reactive` for arrays.
2. use `() => packagesList.value.length` to watch the array length.
3. `deep: true` is for objects

Playground

```js
const { createApp, ref, watch } = Vue
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia

const Store = defineStore('global',
  () => {
    const packagesList = ref([])    
    function getSearch() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            packagesList.value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        }, 1000);
    }  
    return { packagesList, getSearch}
  })

const App = {
  setup() {
    const store = Store()
    const { packagesList } = storeToRefs(store)

    setTimeout(()=>{
      store.getSearch()
    },1000)

    watch(
      () => packagesList.value.length,
      (count, prevCount) => {
        console.log(count, prevCount)
      }
    )    
    return {
      store, packagesList
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
packagesList:  {{packagesList}}
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.30/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script>
```

If define your array with `reactive` like

```
const packagesList = reactive([])
```

and then try to assign it

```
packagesList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

then you will get the JS Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

I simply always use `ref` to omit such problems at all.